# How can I join a Slackware desktop to an AD network?

Tags: linux, active-directory, slackware

It's been a long time since I last used Slackware professionally and the opportunity arose once more. How can I join it to my company's network that's using Microsoft AD?

Comment: What do you mean by "join it to the network?" Are you talking about signing into a wireless network with AD credentials? Accessing shared or network storage?

Comment: I mean using the AD user on the Slackware box.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have used `sssd` to do this.
https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/

Here is their official document on connecting to Active Directory: https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Configuring_sssd_with_ad_server

Answer (score 0):

Slackware 15 use this link. Adapt it and you will see that it works for you.
https://www.datasunrise.com/professional-info/integrating-ubuntu-with-ad/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1161022)

Comment: Sorry. I am a beginner. Thanks you for the tip

Comment: It would be best for your answer if you followed my advice above.  Just edit your question and expand it.  Otherwise, the bot may delete it, it being a link-only answer.